# $\lambda([n,\infty)) \ge1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Is $\lambda([n,\infty)) \ge1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ true?
If so, then I actually do not understand why? Because $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ means $n\to\infty$. So in this case $\lambda([n,\infty))=0$, right?

Comment: Let $n\in\mathbb{N} $, then $\lambda([n,\infty)) = \lambda([n,n+1])+\lambda((n+1,\infty))$.

Comment: @chrispy thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lambda([n, \infty)) = +\infty (\ge 1)$ (if we mean Lebesgue measure, which is suggested by use of $\lambda$ in a real numbers setting).

$[n, \infty)$ has nothing to do with limits, it's just a notation for $\{x \in \Bbb R\mid x \ge n\}$.

To see the value of the measure we *can* use a limit, as $\lambda([n,m))= m-n$ for all natural numbers $m \ge n$ and $[n, \infty) = \bigcup_{m > n} [n, m)$ so the "continuity" of the measure tells us that $\lambda(n, \infty) = \lim_{m \to \infty} (m-n)  = +\infty$ for any fixed $n$. Or use that $[n, \infty)$ is covered by countably many disjoint sets $[m,m+1)$ where $m \in \Bbb N, m > n$ which are pairwise disjoint, so we add infinitely many $1$'s to get $\lambda([n,\infty))$. Etc.

To address the comment: $\bigcap_n [n, \infty) = \emptyset$ so $\lambda(\bigcap_n [n, \infty))=0$. This is no problem as the "continuity law" $$\lambda(\bigcap_n A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n)$$ for decreasing $A_n$, *only* holds if at least one $A_n$ has *finite* measure, which is not the case here. This example in fact shows the necessity of that last condition.

Comment: @Anacardium I added some thoughts on that. BTW $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda([n, \infty))$ is not $0$ it's $+\infty$ as we have the limit of a constant sequence.